# Square root of the second derivative operator

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $p>1$ and $X=L^p(a,b)$ be the space of $L^p$-integrable functions on $(a,b)$ and consider the operator 
$A f = f''$ with domain $D(A)=W^{2,p}(a,b)\cap W^{1,p}_0(a,b)$. Now, my question is : can we say that the square root $(-A)^\frac{1}{2}$ coincides with the first derivative on $(a,b)$?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714040/what-is-the-square-root-of-the-laplace-operator?rq=1).

Comment: The first derivative is not positive or self-adjoint. Hence, it cannot be the square root.

Comment: You should first clarify what you mean by the square root of an unbounded operator on $L^p$ (unless $p=2$, this is not a Hilbert space).