Integration by parts with $|\nabla|:=\sqrt{-\Delta}$
What conditions on $f,g$ do I need to justify the integration by parts $$\int f|\nabla|g\,dx=\int(|\nabla|f)g\,dx.$$From $|\nabla|:=\sqrt{-\Delta}$ we have formally that $|\nabla|$ is a self-adjoint operator on $L^2$, i.e. $$(f,|\nabla |g)=(|\nabla| f,g).$$
But don't we need conditions on $f,g$ so that the boundary data are $0$?

I'm not an expert on this, but I don't think so since we are not really integrating by parts. By this I mean that a proof of this identity will not involve IBP, but rather by manipulating integrals/sums using whichever definition of $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ you are using. That said, there should be some condition on $f,g$ that ensures that the integrals exists and that the functions are smooth enough etc (similar to the conditions mentioned here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1714085/147873 ).

What does your notation mean?

Your definition of $-\Delta$ should also include some boundary information. The Laplacian is only self-adjoint if certain boundary conditions are also imposed. I suspect that in specifying this appropriately, your question will be answered

Out of curiosity, what’s any justification for the notation $\vert\nabla\vert$?

@Aruralreader This is fairly common notation. Using the Fourier transform, we have (for suitably nice functions) that $$ \widehat{(-\Delta f)}(\xi) = \vert \xi \vert^2 \hat{f}(\xi). $$ Thus, often we denote by $g(-i\nabla)$ or $g(p)$ the operator which in Fourier space is given by $$ \widehat{g((-i\nabla) f)}(\xi) = g(\xi) \hat{f}(\xi). $$ It is just very convenient to express the pseudodifferential operator in this fashion (morally what one does is to diagonalize the Laplacian with the Fourier transform and then modify the eigenvalues as for the spectral theorem).

Well, probably I should have written $$ \widehat{\partial_j f}(\xi) = i\xi_j \hat{f}(\xi) $$ to drive my point home.

‘This is fairly common notation.’ Thank you, @SeverinSchraven, out here in the sticks several of us are still catching up with notations.

@Aruralreader I did not mean to be dismissive! It is just what people working with pseudo-differential operators call those things (with the motivation I gave above in mind). Sometimes they also write $p(D)$ instead.

Not taken as dismissive in the slightest. Thank you @SeverinSchraven.

@Aruralreader One last thing before I'll shut up for real. It might help to understand that these things were developed with PDEs in mind. Namely if you want to solve $$\sum_{\vert \alpha\vert\leq d} a_\alpha \partial_1^{\alpha_1}\dots \partial_n^{\alpha_n} f =h,$$ then that looks kind of hopeless, but after using the Fourier transform this becomes $$p(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)=\hat{h}(\xi)$$ with $p$ a polynomial. If we could divide by $p$ and take the invverse Fourier transform, we would get ourselves a solution of our PDE! It's also useful for spectral theory (Weyl law etc).

If $f,g\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then we can just use the Fourier transform to get
$$ \int f(x) (\vert \nabla \vert g)(x) dx = \int \hat{f}(\xi) \widehat{\vert \nabla \vert g}(\xi) d\xi = \int \hat{f}(\xi) \vert \xi \vert \hat{g}(\xi) d \xi = \dots = \int (\vert \nabla \vert f)(x) g(x) dx. $$
If you want to use this for a different function space, you will first find a suitable definition of what $\vert \nabla \vert f$ is supposed to mean (typically you want to define it in Fourier space as a multiplication operator as I have used it above).

What are the steps to go from $\widehat{\vert\nabla\vert g}(\xi)$ to $\vert\xi\vert\hat{g}(\xi)$?

@Aruralreader This is how one typically defines the operator $\vert \nabla \vert$ (as a multiplication operator in Fourier space). You want a square root of the operator $(-\Delta)$ which in Fourier space is the multiplication operator by $\vert \xi \vert^2$.
